# Cross-compiling libraries for ARM device

Tags: c++, qt4, arm, portability, abi

I am experiencing some difficulties in deploying a sample application which uses Qt libraries to an ARM device. I compiled the libraries using the cross-compiler provided for my system, I copied the binaries to the device and I compiled with the same compiler a sample appliction. When I try to start it this is what I get;

> /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3' not found (required by ./libQtNetwork.so.4)
>
> /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3' not found (required by ./libQtCore.so.4)

What could be causing this? I used the toolchain provided by the manufacturer, so it should be ok... Is it possible that the compiler is correct but it is linking not to the libstc++ it is provided with but with the libstdc++ I have in my system, following the link path?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems the version of `libstdc++` you are using at runtime is a different version than the one being used by the toolchain during the build.

Comment: By version you mean they are compiled with different compilers or different version numbers? Because the one shipped with the toolchain has the same version number of the one in the device, and I suppose it is compiled with the same compiler as well. So, maybe, during my compilation, I'm using the correct compiler but it is compiling against the x86 libraries. How can I check this and force to use the ARM libs?

Comment: I tried to compile a sample application which only uses C++ standard library, crosscompiling for ARM, and in fact the problem remains. How do I force the compiler to use the ARM compiled std libs instead of those I have in my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the first comment to my question was exactly the solution. The version of the library was the same but was not compatible. I moved that library to the device and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I have a FriendlyARM that was shipped with a GCC toolchain. To generate correct code I need to specify by hand `-mcpu`, `-mfp`, `-mabi` and `-mabi-float`.

If you build your own GCC you may set the defaults, but at least in my devkit, they came with the wrong defaults.